# Error in breaking a loop during its execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Hello I was trying to break the loop in middle of its execution.The loop shows a countdown of seconds from 5-1 .I want to break the loop in middle using any keystroke entered by the user.I researched for some time and created a thread. I set a global variable and updated it in the second thread. I gave a condition in the main function using that global variable but the loop doesn't break.

Here is the code.
Please help.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<windows.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<iomanip>
 #include<stdio.h>
 using namespace std;

 bool stop=false;

 DWORD WINAPI thread1(LPVOID pm)
{
//check the getchar value
int a = getchar();
while (a != '0'){
    a = getchar();
}
stop = true;
return 0;
}
int main()
{

  HANDLE handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread1, NULL, 0, NULL);
  for(int i=5;i>0 && !stop;i--)
  {
    cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    cout<<setw(35);
    cout<<i;
    Sleep(1000);
    system("CLS");
 }
  system("PAUSE");
}
```

The program counts down and in middle of the count down i tried to break the loop.thread1 function takes an input and modifies stop(global variable). But the loop in main function doesn't break(it should).Loop goes on decreasing loop variable, becomes zero and loop ends.

Comment: Can we have some examples of what you obtain and what you want ?

Comment: And, personnaly, I will inverse thread, to kill downcounting thread immediatly from main thread

Comment: @Garf365 I want to break the loop in main(). And please elaborate the inverse thread part.

Comment: You don't have explain what is the behavior you expect and what is the problem with current code

Comment: @Garf365 .Now i have.

Comment: `getchar()` does not return immediately after a key is pressed; it waits for you to enter an entire line of text before it returns. Since you are using the Windows API, you can use the console functions that come with the Windows API to read input directly instead. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. getchar() was waiting for carriage return. So i used _getch() from conio library. Like this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
volatile bool stop = false;
DWORD WINAPI thread1(LPVOID pm)
{
  int a = 0;
  while (a==0)
  {
    a = _getch();
  }
  stop = true;
  return 0;
}

 int main()
{
  HANDLE handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread1, NULL, 0, NULL);
  int i;
  for ( i = 5; i > 0 && !stop; i--)
  {
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    cout << setw(35);
    cout << i;
    Sleep(1000);
    system("CLS");
  } 
   if (i != 0)
    cout << "Loop broken sucessflly.\n";
   else
    cout << "Attempt failed\n";
   system("PAUSE");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare stop as volatile

```
volatile bool stop
```

It informs compiler not optimized (by cache) access to variable, because another thread can modify it.

Also, take care about read and write access on global variable by many thread : in most of case, you have to protect them using mutex. (I think in your case it's not necessary according basic small type and basic access, but take care)

**EDIT**

As ask in comments, this is my design when inverting thread :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

volatile bool stop = false;

DWORD WINAPI thread1(LPVOID pm)
{
    for(int i=5;i>0 && !stop;i--)
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        cout<<setw(35);
        cout<<i;
        Sleep(1000);
        system("CLS");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread1, NULL, 0, NULL);
    //check the getchar value
    int a = getchar();
    while (a != '0'){
        a = getchar();
    }
    stop = true;
    WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

With this solution, it will stop after waiting 1s. If you want to terminate immediatly, you can use `TerminateThread` but read this before : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Made my variable volatile but still can't break.